# Storing OneSignal IDs with Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, onesignal

I'm trying to figure out the "correct" way to set up push notifications on an Ionic v3 app using the OneSignal SDK and native plugin (iOS is all I care about, for the moment).  My goal is to set up an observer using the addSubscriptionObserver hook provided by the plugin, and update my database with the userId when the user opts in to notifications.  I believe the problem I'm having has to do with the scope the callback is running in.  I am trying to access the userService (injected into the component where the subscriptionObserver is added), but I am getting the following error when the callback runs:

`2018-04-22 09:59:53.977213-0700 WodaX[2610:692168] Error in Success callbackId: OneSignalPush492317370 : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.userService.updateUserOneSignalId')`

Here is my code:

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.statusBar.styleDefault();
        this.statusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
        this.keyboard.disableScroll(false);
        this.splashScreen.hide();
        // OneSignal Code start:
        // Enable to debug issues:
        //window["plugins"].OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});

        let notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
            console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
        };

        let iosSettings = {};
        iosSettings["kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt"] = false;
        window["plugins"].OneSignal
            .startInit("[MY_ONE_SIGNAL_APP_ID]")
            .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
            .inFocusDisplaying(window["plugins"].OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
            .iOSSettings(iosSettings)
            .endInit();
        window["plugins"].OneSignal.addPermissionObserver(this.handlePermissionChange);
        window["plugins"].OneSignal.addSubscriptionObserver(this.handleSubscriptionChange);
    });
}

openPage(page) {
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
}

private handleSubscriptionChange(data: any) {
  console.log(data)
    if (data.to.userSubscriptionSetting && data.to.userId) {
    let userUuid = "testId"
        this.userService.updateUserOneSignalId(userUuid, data.to.userId).subscribe((res) => {
    console.log(res);
        }, (err) => {
    console.log(err);
        });
    }
}
```

The same call to the userService method works in a the getIds callback in a different component, so I'm guessing this has something to do with how the callbacks are registered by the addSubscriptionObserver method.

Here is the operative plugin code:

```
OneSignal.prototype.addSubscriptionObserver = function(callback) {
  OneSignal._subscriptionObserverList.push(callback);
  var subscriptionCallBackProcessor = function(state) {
    OneSignal._processFunctionList(OneSignal._subscriptionObserverList, state);
  };
  cordova.exec(subscriptionCallBackProcessor, function(){}, "OneSignalPush", "addSubscriptionObserver", []);
}
```

I'd appreciate insight from anyone who may have successfully set this up. The goal is to be able to store individual OneSignal Ids so users can trigger notifications to other users.  I can do this now, but only if I do it when the user accepts the prompt.  I need to be able to do it anytime they opt in to push notifications, even from the settings after declining the original prompt.

Comment: Try changing private handleSubscriptionChange(data:any) {} to handleSubscriptionChange = (data:any) => { }

Comment: You have ‘scope’ issue most likely when this method is called your ‘this’ is not your component scope. Try doing console.log(this) to check that

Comment: I'm embarrassed I didn't think to try it as an arrow function...this did the trick.  If you make this an answer, I will accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you have faced pretty common pitfall handling 'this' during a call of a function with a callback method.
Normally if you see those "undefined" type of errors you want to console.log 'this' (console.log(this)) to see which scope 'this' points at and then decide a fix.

In your case I would use fat arrow function assignment for handleSubscriptionChange method:

- instead: handleSubscriptionChange(data:any) => {...}
- do:    handleSubscriptionChange = (data:any) => {...}

Fat arrow function doesn't create its own 'this' and in this case should solve you problem.